# how to extract words from a string with special characters

Tags: regex, ocaml

I am currently trying to do a spellcheck, but am having some trouble dealing with certain cases.

For example, given the string: { else"--but, }, my spellcheck automatically reads this as an invalid word. However, since else and but are both correctly spelled, I don't want to mark this as incorrect.

Is there any way I can do this with regular expressions?
A more common case I am having trouble with is things like "waistcoat-pocket".

Comment: You need to provide some code because it is hard to guess the actual situation. Why don't you just filter out certain characters before spell checking?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a regular expression, you should use unicode word segmentation. With the uuseg and uucp library, you can extract words and filter word boundaries with

```
let is_alphaword =
  let alphachar = function
    | `Malformed _ -> false
    | `Uchar x ->
      match Uucp.Break.word x with
      | `LE | `Extend -> true
      | _ -> false
     in
  Uutf.String.fold_utf_8 (fun acc _ x -> acc && alphachar x) true
  (* Note that we are supposing strings to be utf-8 encoded *)

let words s =
  let cons l x = if is_alphaword x then x :: l else l in
  List.rev (Uuseg_string.fold_utf_8 `Word cons  [] s)
```

This function splits the string words-by-words:

```
words "else\"--but";;
- : string list = ["else"; "but"]
```

```
words "waistcoat-pocket";;
- : string list = ["waistcoat"; "pocket"]
```

and works correctly in more general context

```
words "आ तवेता नि षीदतेन्द्रमभि पर गायत";;
- : string list =
["आ"; "तवेता"; "नि"; "षीदतेन्द्रमभि";
 "पर"; "गायत"]
```

or

```
words "Étoile(de Barnard)";;
- : string list = ["Étoile"; "de"; "Barnard"]
```